# Disassociate ID from one stack exchange site

Tags: support

I'd like to disassociate my ID from one particular stack exchange site (english.stackexchange) without affecting my other stack exchange profiles. Can this be done? How, if yes?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Do you mean delete your EL&U account :-( or just disassociate it (still keep the account, but have it not connected to your other login)?

Comment: Well I use OpenID to login to all my stack exchange accounts.. so in that context, I'm not sure what, if any, difference there is between deleting vs disassociating. But yea, I'd like it to not show up in my "list of stack exchange sites" on my profile page, i guess.

Comment: Re-reading your comment, i see now what you were asking. Yes, I'd like to delete my EL&U account. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the content of the "About Me" textarea to "please delete me"; then, go to https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/help, and click on "Delete my user profile" (it is listed under "Account Management"). On the page you are taken, there is a form that needs to be filled.

After you do that, they will take care of your account. Generally, it takes some days to do that, but they will delete your account as you requested.